# What biblical canon do Eastern Catholic Churches use?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, canon, deuterocanonical-books, eastern-catholicism

The Roman Catholic Church and Eastern Orthodox Church use slightly different biblical canons: [Books of the Bible (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_the_Bible?wprov=sfti1).  Notably, the Orthodox Church uses 3 Maccabees and 4 Maccabees while the Roman Catholic Church does not (at least not in the Latin Rite).

However, I can’t find any information about what biblical canon the Eastern Catholic Churches use.  These are the churches like the Marionite Church, the Melkite Greek Catholic Church, etc... that are in full communion with the Latin Rite of the Catholic Church, but are often considered part of Eastern Christianity.

Do these Eastern Catholic churches use the Roman Catholic canon, the Eastern Orthodox Canon, or some mix of the two?  Does it differ from Church to Church?

This is especially interesting to me because it seems like some Eastern Catholic communities were once in schism with the Roman Catholic Church but returned to full communion sometime later: [Eastern Catholic Churches (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Catholic_Churches?wprov=sfti1).

Any historical perspective or info from Eastern Catholics themselves would be much appreciated!